# Ghosting on second monitor

Tags: display

I bought a new iMac (2020 and Catalina) with 64G of RAM and when I plugged my second monitor (an old Cinema Display 23", I get ghosting on that monitor. Any fixes?

Thanks

Comment: What cables/adapters are you using? MacTracker indicates that this monitor has only a DVI video connection. If you connect this monitor to another computer (if you can) with the same cable, is the ghosting still there?

Comment: Hi,, ThanksI bought an adapter from DVI to USB-C (as required and I used the adapter immediately upon receiving it , a Landosend LSVTR ) and I can't realy plugs my old monitor using that particular adapter (my older iMac had a different adapter Thhunderbolt 1 to DVI)

Comment: Must be the adapter. Cheap one!

Comment: I trust [Belkin cables and adaptors](http://amazon.com/Belkin-Mini-Displayport-Adapter-F2CD029bt/dp/B00E9646RE) over any other brand. _Disclaimer: no financial or other ties to Belkin - just damn good, rugged adaptors._

Comment: Right! I should have known!